# Excel: Avoid/Shorten multiple SUMIF?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a formula in my Excel sheet that looks like this:

```
1000 - SUMIF($B:$B;"A1400";$A:$A) - SUMIF($B:$B;"B1400";$A:$A) - SUMIF($B:$B;"C1400";$A:$A) - ...
```

And there are a lot more SUMIF that follow. Is there a way to avoid writing it like this, to condense the ~15 SUMIF statements? For example, can I tell Excel to draw the criteria (A1400, B1400, C1400) from a cell range or an array?

Comment: you can add a helper column to mark if data need to be considered. (e.g. enter your criteria values to column X, then in Column C you can write `=COUNTIF(X:X;B2)`, and your complex formula will be `=1000-SUMIF(C:C;">0";A:A)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array in the criteria if you wrap in SUMPRODUCT:

```
=1000 - SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF($B:$B;{"A1400","B1400","C1400"};$A:$A))
```

You can also put the list of criteria in a range and use that range.  For example if the criteria was in Z1:Z3:

```
=1000 - SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF($B:$B;Z1:Z3;$A:$A))
```

In these cases there will be done 3 SUMIFS and the results will be added, then that result will be subtracted from `1000`

Comment: criteria in the question is text, not range

Comment: Thank you. This should work with SUMIFS as well, right? So `SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS($A:$A;$B:$B;Z1:Z3;$C:$C;Y1:Y3))`? The intention is to  sum if the criteria-pairs Z1/Y1, Z1/Y2, Z1/Y3, Z2/Y1 etc. are fulfilled.

Comment: @Alex you will need to transpose one of the ranges: `SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS($A:$A;$B:$B;Z1:Z3;$C:$C;Transpose(Y1:Y3)))` and it will only work with two, you cannot do a third.

Comment: @ScottCraner Makes sense, thanks again. Out of curiosity, what would you do if you wanted to add a third criterion? Would you have to use a different construct entirely?

Comment: You would need a different formula array type formula @alex